# WPF application error 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have created WPF application in Visual Studio 2010 when I run the application in Visual Studio 2017 it generating following error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.' Line number '8' and line position '18'. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource 'resourcedic/maindictionary.xaml'.
```

Following is the app.xaml file that I am using in the application:-

```
<Application x:Class="AttendenceSystem.UI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="StartWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDic\MainDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>    
</Application>
```

Anybody help me to resolve this issue. If you need any further details please let me know.

Comment: You need to post the XAML of the offending file, all we can say is you have a missing or incorrectly specified resource.

Comment: I am unable to post the maindictionary.xaml file because StackOverflow allows only 3000 characters in the question. Could you suggest me how can I post that file?

Comment: Well, the problem is on Line 8, so only post the first 10 or so lines.

Comment: I have updated the XMAL file code please see.

Comment: I don't think the error is occurring in `maindictionary.xaml`, it is in some other file. Does the debugger break and tell you what file is throwing the error? It is some file that is trying to load your `maindictionary`, not the dictionary itself.

Comment: The debugger is not working when I run the application is showing me a message "The Application is in break mode" and then I click on "Continues Execution" link then error displaying under "Output" tab.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I had to add this itemGroup to the .csproj of the project

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf">
    <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
    <Version>12.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```